# Substitute a 4 digit number by its first digit

Tags: r

The problem is:

I have 7 columns on which over 30% of the rows are NAs. All my columns are numeric.

On these High Missing Values Columns I want to create 4 new columns base on the values of the these columns' quantiles.

```
1st column- input 1 in rows which contains data; 0 otherwise
2nd column- input 1 in rows below the first quantile; 0 otherwise
3rd column- input 1 in rows that are in the 2nd quantile range; 0 otherwise
4th column- input 1 in rows that are above the 3rd quantile; 0 otherwise
```

I got the first column. But the rest, based on the quantiles' threshold value has been a challenge.

My next 3 columns are base on just 3 quantiles: 33.33333%,  66.66667%   and   100%

```
quantile(High_NAS_set1$EFX, prob=c(33/99,66/99,99/99),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
#1st column: assign 1 for a row that contains data; 0 otherwise

New.EFX_<-High_NAS_set1$EFX #creating a new column


New.EFX_Emp_Total[!is.na(New.EFX)]<-1
New.EFX_Emp_Total[is.na(New.EFX)]<-0


#2nd Column:assign 1 in rows below the first quantile; 0 otherwise

New.EFX2_<-High_NAS_set1$EFX #creating a new column

quant<-quantile(New2.EFX_Emp,probs=33/99,na.rm=TRUE)

which(New2.EFX_Emp_Total<=quant)<-1  # assign 1 for rows which indexes are below quant
which(New2.EFX_Emp_Total!=quant)<-0
```

The last 2 lines are giving me an error:

```
Error in which(New2.EFX_Emp_Total <= quant) <- 1 : 
  could not find function "which<-"
```

Comment: First, I'm not an R programmer, so what I'd do as a PHP developer is divide #### by 1000, then round it down to the nearest whole number.

Comment: It is not the way to use `which`. `New2.EFX_Emp_Total[which(New2.EFX_Emp_Total<=quant)] <- 1`

Comment: You *are* aware that 33/99 is 1/3? and 99/99 is 1?  Keep the code simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
qtl <- quantile(High_NAS_set1$EFX, prob=c(1/3, 2/3, 1), na.rm=TRUE)

High_NAS_set1$EFX033 <- ifelse(High_NAS_set1$EFX <= qtl[1], 1, 0)
High_NAS_set1$EFX066 <- ifelse(High_NAS_set1$EFX <= qtl[2], 1, 0)
High_NAS_set1$EFX100 <- ifelse(High_NAS_set1$EFX <= qtl[3], 1, 0)
```